# Hibernate about non-primary-key Association

Tags: hibernate

i tried to use hibernate anntation about @OneToMany to handle two entities association, when i use primary-key column mapped with anntation @FechMode.SubSelect can filter records  (console will print subselect SQL statement) solve problem of 1+n.
when i use non-primary-key column mapped with anntation @FechMode.SubSelect ,it's seem doesn't work well, i got repetition records, i think is problem of 1+n.

ah, @FechMode.SubSelect only support primary-key column mapped association to solve 1+n right?

any 1 know that?   thank U

like this :

Class A {

```
@Id
private Long aId;

private String aSN;

@OneTOMany(mappedBy="a")
@FechMode.SubSelect
private List<B> bList;

...
```

}

Class B {

```
@Id
private Long bId;

private String bSN;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="bSN",referencedColumnName="aSN")
private A a

...
```

}